# How to position the image relatively

Tags: html, css

Hai I am new in html and css.I need some help.I have 4 images given below.
[image]
The main Background image

[image]
Link image1

[image]
Link image2

[image]
Link image13

And I need to look the all images finally like

[image]
Final Look

My html is like

```
<div class="aside__block social-media-follow">
<div class="aside-block__content">
<img src="/media/19134/001.jpg"/>
<a href="#"><img src="/media/19133/Twetter.jpg"/></a>?
<a href="#"><img src="/media/19133/facebok.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="/media/19133/insta.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Can any one help on css to position the social link images.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Comment: first create a fiddle or put some css here
http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you can use absolute position for images

Comment: create a `div with the background-image`, create a `div for the three icons`, create a div + class for each icon. Give the class for the icon a `float right` and a `margin-right` = your done

Comment: There are tons of ways to do this. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/StjhN/)

Comment: that's a lot of images for something you could create only with pure html and css. have you ever tried font icons? check this out: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="aside__block social-media-follow">
<div class="aside-block__content">
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxD7P.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBlEE.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbE0s.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

In css:

```
.aside-block__content  {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmci.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 310px;
  height: 100px;
}

.aside-block__content a img{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

DEMO : http://jsbin.com/kexam/1/edit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the "follow us" image as a background image and float the icons right with margin-top and right to position them as desired :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/n7Cr5/)**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="aside__block social-media-follow">
    <div class="aside-block__content"> 
        <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBlEE.jpg"/></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxD7P.jpg"/></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbE0s.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.aside-block__content {
    width:314px;
    height:115px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/msmci.jpg);
}

.aside-block__content a{
    float:right;
    margin:50px 30px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the <img src="/media/19134/001.jpg"/> as you have specified it in the .aside-block__content as background-image

Comment: @mohamedrias you are right, I added the html in the answer  to show that.

Comment: Cool, Before it was not there so i was afraid

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

You could do this by...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper with the background - image -->
  <div id="social_media"> <!-- a container for the social media icons -->
    <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="/media/19133/Twetter.jpg"/></a> <!-- Your Icons -->
    <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="/media/19133/facebok.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="icon" src="/media/19133/insta.jpg"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#wrapper { background: url(/media/19134/001.jpg) no-repeat; }
#social_media { /*  Your positioning */ }
.icon { float:right; margin-left: 20px; }
```